# Get WEKA Instances from java objects

Tags: java, weka

I have a `Set<User>` object in my java code. This is the source of User class:

```
public class User {
  private String id;
  private String bDate;
  private String name;
  private String sName;
  private String description;
  private String city;

  ... getters/setters
}
```

Can you show some example, how can I use it in Clusterer in WEKA?

Comment: You need to create a .arff file for your data as defined here: http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html  You can use string data instead of numeric. Then you can import the data to Weka.

Comment: @xro7 Is there any way to do it in java code without redundant writing a file?

Comment: I am not sure. I just did it by myself. i will try to post my code here to match your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to include opencsv to your project from here: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ in order to print your data in csv format.

I use one writer to write the csv data and another to write the arff format.

```
        writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(pathtoyourfile+".arff",true), "utf-8"));
        writer2 =  new PrintWriter(pathtoyourfile+".arff", "UTF-8");
        writer2.println("@Relation Users");
        writer2.println("");
        writer2.println("@attribute id string");
        writer2.println("@attribute bDate string");
        writer2.println("@attribute name string");
        writer2.println("@attribute sName string");
        writer2.println("@attribute description string");
        writer2.println("@attribute city string");          
        writer2.println("");
        writer2.println("@data");
        writer2.close();

        String[] entries =  new String[6];
        //lets say you have a list with users
        List<User>  users = .....

        for(int i=0;i<users.size();i++){
             entries[0]= users.get(i).getId();
             entries[1]= users.get(i).getbDate();
             .....
             entries[5]= users.get(i).getCity();
             writer.writeNext(entries);
        }
        writer.close();
```